# Adding a point geometry to Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I want to insert a point geometry to PostgreSQL Db with the following method but I get an error which I don't know it comes.

```
const point = {type:"Point",coordinates:[-48.23456,20.12345]}
tableName.create({ geom: point }, user_id: 9 })



"error": {
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 128,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22023",
        "file": "gserialized_typmod.c",
        "line": "164",
        "routine": "postgis_valid_typmod",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"gps_tracking\" (\"id\",\"created\",\"user_id\",\"geom\") VALUES (DEFAULT,now(),$1,ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($2)) RETURNING *;",
        "parameters": [
            9,
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -48.23456,
                    20.12345
                ]
            }
        ]
 }
```

Comment: Did you try to execute this SQL query directly and look at an error you get?

Answer (score 1):

adding the "crs" line solved my question. Thanks

```
const point = {
     type: 'Point',
     coordinates: [39.807222, -76.984722],
     crs: { type: 'name', properties: { name: 'EPSG:4326' } }
 };
```